# Ubuntu 22.04.1 wake up immediatly after suspend

Tags: ubuntu, kde-plasma

My system is Ubuntu 22.04.1 with Plasma desktop. Every time I click suspend/sleep button, the system goes to sleep and then wake up immediately. I could not find the cause.

Comment: Wrong site. You're looking for [ubuntu.se] instead. This site is for programming-related questions only. You can find more information in the [help].